# How to remove ellipsis at the end of Strings in R

Tags: r, regex, ellipsis

I have list of words, which i got from below code.

```
tags_vector <- unlist(tags_used)
```

Some of the strings in this list has ellipsis in the end,which i want to remove. Here i print the 5th element of this list, and its class

```
tags_vector[5]
#[1] "#b…"

class(tags_vector[5])
#[1] "character"
```

I am trying to remove the ellipsis from this 5th element using `gsub`, using the code ,

```
gsub("[…]", "", tags_vector[5])
#[1] "#b…"
```

This code doesn't works and i get "#b…" as output. But in the same code when i  put the value of 5th element directly, it works fine as below,

```
gsub("[…]", "", "#b…")
#[1] "#b"
```

I even tried putting the value of `tags_vector[5]` in a variable `x1` and tried to use it in `gsub()` code but it still din't work.

Comment: Could you provide `tags_vector`? It works for me with a simple `x <- "#b..."`, so I guess it has to do with your vector.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/61hWht, it seems to work. BTW, since the ellipsis is not ASCII, you might try with stringr `str_replace_all`: `library(stringr)` -> `str_replace_all(tags_vector[5], "…", "")`

Comment: It indeed seems to be a unicode issue. It could be that the print of tags_vector[5] already changes the character (e.g. there are two different unicodes for the ellipsis: [2026](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) and [22EF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22EF/index.htm)). This would also explain why the direct gsub does work. Could you try `gsub(gsub("[#b]","",tags_vector[5]), "", tags_vector[5])` ?

Comment: Since it could be an encoding issue, could you also show the results of sessionInfo()?

Answer (score 2):

It might be a Unicode issue. In R(studio), not all characters are created equally.

I tried to create a reproducible example:

```
# create the ellipsis from the definition (similar to your tags_used)
> ell_def <- rawToChar(as.raw(c('0xE2','0x80','0xA6'))) # from the unicode definition here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm
> Encoding(ell_def) <- 'UTF-8'
> ell_def
[1] "…"
> Encoding(ell_def)
[1] "UTF-8"

# create the ellipsis from text (similar to your string)
> ell_text <- '…'
> ell_text
[1] "…"
> Encoding(ell_text)
[1] "latin1"

# show that you can get strange results
> gsub(ell_text,'',ell_def)
[1] "…"
```

The reproducibility of this example might be dependent on your locale. In my case, I work in windows-1252 since you cannot set the locale to UTF-8 in Windows. According to [this stringi source](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.1.2/topics/stringi-encoding), "R lets strings in ASCII, UTF-8, and your platform's native encoding coexist peacefully". As the example above shows, this might sometimes give contradictory results.

Basically, the output you see looks the same, but isn't on a byte level.

If I run this example in the R terminal, I get similar results, but apparently, it shows the ellipsis as a dot: ".".

A quick fix for your example would be to use the ellipsis definition in your gsub. E.g.:

```
gsub(ell_def,'',tags_vector[5])
```